# How to remove bunched duplicate elements but keep one

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
my_list =`['A', 'B', 'C', '!', '!', 'D', 'E', '!', '!', '!', 'F', 'G', '!']
```

I would like to print out this list such that whenever there is a gap between the letters 'A' through 'G' (whenever a '!' occurs), only one single '!' is printed out.

So if I were to change this list so then I could print out the elements, the list would look like this:

```
new_list =`['A', 'B', 'C', '!', 'D', 'E', '!', 'F', 'G', '!']
```

I am essentially trying to indicate that there is a gap between the letters, not about the size of the gap.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
In [30]: res = [i[0] for i in itertools.groupby(my_list)]

In [31]: res
Out[31]: ['A', 'B', 'C', '!', 'D', 'E', '!', 'F', 'G', '!']
```